# Relation satisfied by a Gaussian random variable

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, convexity, gaussian, expectation

I want to prove the following relation for $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\mathbb{E}[\max(X,x)]$:
$$f(\frac{f(x+1)+f(x-1)}{2})\leq \frac{f(f(x)-1)+f(f(x)+1)}{2}$$
It seems that convexity of $f$ is not enough..., indeed, if $R$ is a Rademacher $=\pm 1$ with proba $0.5$, then the LHS is $f(\mathbb{E}[f(x+R)])$ and the RHS is $\mathbb{E}[f(f(x)+R)]$. From convexity of $f$, both are larger than $f(f(x))$, but it is not clear which one is the largest...

Comment: Can you let us know how this problem arises?

Comment: We pose 3 lotteries: --(1)--> $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ --(2)--> $\mathcal{N}(R,1)$, where $R$ is a Rademacher $+-1$ with proba .5 --(3)--> determinist, $=x$. Once you choose a lottery, you gain the drawn outcome. Then, you can either stop here and keep this outcome or choose any of the remaining ones by losing this outcome. How to play this game? The determinist lottery has to be played in the end, and only when the current outcome is lower than $x$. The more difficult question is to determine which of the $X$ and $X+R$ lottery to play first. If the inequality is true, $X+R$ has to be played first.

Comment: As context, the function $f(x)$ is close to $f_0(x)=\max(x,0)$, with the error $f(x)-f_0(x)$ being positive, even in $x$ and extremely small for reasonably large $x$.  If we replace $f$ by $f_0$ then the desired inequality is an equality for $x\geq 0$, and is strictly satisfied for $x<0$.

Comment: It may help that according to Mathematica, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(LHS-x)x^2e^{x^2/2-x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi e}}$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(RHS-x)x^2e^{x^2/2-x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi e}}$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(RHS-LHS)x^4e^{x^2-x}=\frac{1}{4\pi\sqrt{e}}$$

Comment: Hmmm, this seems promising, particularly the last relation. Perhaps the same kind of behavior appear for (RHS-LHS)’ and for higher order derivatives, allowing to determine the sign of the Taylor series (I guess it is alternating).